# How to use Observable pattern with Firebase on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, observable

I am trying to implement a room booking system with an Observable design pattern using Firebase. I am pretty new to Observable pattern, but I have created the general files as such:

**Subject.java**

```
public interface Subject {
    void Attach(Observer o);
    void Detach(Observer o);
    void refreshAccess();
}
```

**Observer.java**

```
public interface Observer {
    void update(String newAuthorKey);
}
```

**Booking.java**

```
public class Booking implements Subject {
    private String authorKey; //authorKey for the booking
    private ArrayList<Observer> observers; //users registered for the room

    public Booking(){
        observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
    }

    public void Attach(Observer o){
        observers.add(o);
    }

    public void Detach(Observer o){
        observers.remove(o);
    }

    public void refreshAccess(){

    }

    public void refreshAccess(String newAuthorKey){
        this.authorKey = newAuthorKey;
        this.NotifyObservers();
    }

    private void NotifyObservers(){
        for (Observer o:observers)
            o.update(this.authorKey);
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
public class User implements Observer {
    private String authorKey;
    private Subject subject;

    public User(Subject subject){
        this.subject = subject;

        //register itself to the subject
        this.subject.Attach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(String newAuthorKey){
        //get update from subject
        this.authorKey = newAuthorKey;

        //do something according to the update
    }
}
```

Essentially, the idea is that when a room is booked, a new `Booking` object gets initialised, and the user who books it (and any of the other user he chooses to share this booking with) gets added as users into this booking. How can I update this information into Firebase (I have set it up already in my application), and how can I get a list of all the Bookings that each user subscribed to? I have a fragment on my android app that handles all the event listeners, etc, but I have no idea how to link it up to these classes with Firebase at the moment.

Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern Observable works with one or more Observer attached to one ore more Observable.  Try this:

```
public class Booking extends Observable {
    private String authorKey; //authorKey for the booking
    // private ArrayList<Observer> observers; //users registered for the room (no need because Observable holds a list of Observer already)

    public Booking(String authorKey){
        this.authorKey = authorKey;
    }   


public void refreshAccess(){
    nofityObservers(null);
}

public void refreshAccess(String newAuthorKey){
    String oldAuthorKey = this.authorKey;
    this.authorKey = newAuthorKey;
    nofityObservers(oldAuthorKey);
}

@Override
public void notifyObservers(Object arg) {
    setChanged();
    super.notifyObservers(arg);
}
}

public class User implements java.util.Observer {
private ArrayList<String> authorKeys; // to get all bookings a user has

public User(){
}

public void addBooking(Booking b) {
    b.addObserver(this);
}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    if (!(o instanceof Booking ))
        return;
    Booking b = (Booking) o;
    if(arg != null) 
        authorKeys.remove(arg);
    authorKeys.add(b.getAuthorKey());
}
}
```

And somewhere in your system:

```
User u1 = new User();
User u2 = new User();
Booking b = new Booking(authorKey1);
b.addObserver(u1);
b.addObserver(u2);
b.refreshAccess(); // u1 and u2 get notified

b.deleteObserver(u2); // you might want to override this to notify user remove booking info
b.refreshAccess(authorKey2); // u1 get notified
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try to implement this in my project and tell you how it goes